# Does curl download resources

Tags: php, curl

If I use curl to access a page that contains several resources including videos, does curl download these videos as well? If so, how can I prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

curl  will only download the raw HTML source; it won't parse the source at all.